# Riak CS cannot start with log.syslog=on

Tags: riak, riak-cs

In /etc/riak-cs/riak-cs.conf I've changed

```
log.syslog=off
```

to

```
log.syslog=on
```

After that

```
service riak-cs start
```

returns

```
18:33:51.427 [error] Error generating configuration in phase apply_translations
18:33:51.428 [error] Translation for 'lager.handlers' expected to find setting 'log.syslog.ident' but was missing
```

I've added this option in /etc/riak-cs/riak-cs.conf

```
    log.syslog=on
    log.syslog.ident=riakcs
```

But after that it gives me

```
18:18:40.800 [error] Error generating configuration in phase transform_datatypes
18:18:40.800 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: log.syslog.ident
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending Riak CS version, but it seems that you encountered the bug [1].
An workaround to use advanced.config is described in the issue comment [2].

It will be fixed in the coming releases Riak CS 2.1.0.

[1] https://github.com/basho/riak_cs/pull/1162
[2] https://github.com/basho/riak_cs/pull/1162#issuecomment-110550814